# Duplicate permutations in Java program

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I read an algorithm for producing permutations of a string recursively.

> ```
> invoke the function with j = 1
>     if (j == length of string)
>         print the string and return
>     else
>         for (i = j to length of string)
>             interchange jth character with ith character
>             call function on j + 1
> ```

I implemented this using java as following:

```java
class PERMUTATION {
    private int count = 1;
    private char[] arr = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

    public void perm(int k) {
        if (k == 3)  {
            System.out.print(count+++".");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                System.out.print(arr[i]+"  ");
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = k; i <= 3; ++i) {
            /*interchanging ith character with kth character*/
            char c = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = arr[k - 1];
            arr[k - 1] = c;
            perm(k + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("the permutations are");
        PERMUTATION obh=new PERMUTATION();
        obh.perm(1);
    }
}
```

But my program is producing duplicate permutations. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm works if the "source" array remains unchanged, so each index will be treated correctly.

Let's look at the output of your code:

> 1.A  B  C
>   2.A  C  B
>   3.C  A  B
>   4.C  B  A
>   5.A  B  C
>   6.A  C  B

As you can see, in iteration no. 3, where it was supposed to shift *B* to the first index, your shifting *C* instead, because you already moved *B* to a different location.
Due to that fact, *B* has no chance to get on the first index and will only "bounce" between 2 and 3.

Your main problem is, that you're changing the "source" array. If you avoid that, then your algorithm works correctly:

```
class PERMUTATION {
    private int count = 1;

    public void perm(char[] arr, int k) {
        if (k == 3) {
            System.out.print(count++ + ".");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        char[] arr2 = arr.clone(); // clone the passed array, so we don't mess it up
        for (int i = k; i <= 3; ++i) {
            /* interchanging ith character with kth character */
            char c = arr2[k - 1];
            arr2[k - 1] = arr2[i - 1];
            arr2[i - 1] = c;
            perm(arr2, k + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("the permutations are");
        PERMUTATION obh = new PERMUTATION();
        obh.perm(new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C'}, 1); // pass the original array
    }
}
```

The output will then be:

> 1.A  B  C
>   2.A  C  B
>   3.B  A  C
>   4.B  C  A
>   5.C  A  B
>   6.C  B  A

Btw: please mind the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), so don't call your class `PERMUTATION`, use `Permutation` instead.

Comment: Does this mean that space complexity of this algorithm is O(n)?

Comment: @Dante I guess it is a bit more ... maybe O(2n) (due to the 6 endresults) or even O(3n), since we need some recursion, before we've found a single "end result". We are cloning the source array in each `perm` call, so there will be a lot of cloning, but their lifetime is relativly short, so they can be quickly garbage collected.